# Resizing Images npm

Tags: node.js, image, compression, server

In my node server I have a db with full quality images taken by mobile phones. Serving these full images takes too much time so I'll need to compress the images. What are some ideas I can use?

Would it be better to have compressed images in my db or compress them as I serve them?

What are some of the most reliable modules to compress images?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually loading the raw binary data into a database?

Generally this isn't very good for performance as serving images from a database is an expensive operation. The best way is to track the file path of the image in a database and have the application serve it directly via http.

Image resizing / compression is another great way to speed up transfer. I've had a lot of success with this package in the past:

https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

Comment: Yes I am using GridStore, or more specifically Gridjs to save binary files into mongodb. I use streams to read and write the files and http to upload and serve. When it comes to compression, should I keep the full sized image in my db and compress it upon serving it (based on the size of the device that requests it?) or should I save a compressed version into my db and uncompress/serve it as is?